# Issue using Selenium WebdriverJS with FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple JavaScript tests created that use the chromedriver to run tests in Chrome and I now want to run the same tests in FireFox and IE.
This is one of my tests and it works correctly in Chrome with no issues:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');


test.describe('Click current location button.', function () {
    test.it('Seems to have worked.', function () {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
        build();
        // Open Chrome (as specified by the Capabilities above) and go to the specified web page
        driver.get('website url').

        then(function () {

            driver.wait(function () {
                console.log("Looking for username");
                return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('user_username')).isDisplayed();
            }, 5000, 'Page did not load within 5 seconds');

            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("user_username")).sendKeys('user');
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("user_password")).sendKeys('pword');

            return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("signIn")).click();
        }).
        then(function () {

            driver.sleep(4000);

            // make sure page has loaded        
            driver.wait(function () {
                console.log("Looking for current button");
                return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('gaz_input')).isDisplayed();
            }, 5000, 'Page did not load within 5 seconds');

            // Click Accept cookies to prevent issues 
            if (driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//a[@class='cc-cookie-accept']")).isDisplayed()) {
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//a[@class='cc-cookie-accept']")).click();
            }
            driver.sleep(1000);

            // Click the current location button
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//button[@class='btn']")).click();

            console.log("Looking for search results");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000);

            if (!driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-default']")).isDisplayed()) {
                driver.wait(function () {                   
                    return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-default']")).isDisplayed();
                }, 2000, 'Query did not complete within 60 seconds.');
            }

            driver.sleep(1000);
        }).
        then(function () {
            // Close the browser
            return driver.quit();
        });
    });
});
```

So now I want to run this test in FF and IE. I thought that with FF all I had to do was change the capabilities and that it should just work but that didn't happen. 
For IE I thought I just had to just download the IEDriverServer and put it in the same folder as the chromedriver but when I did that and changed the driver capabilities from chrome to internetexplorer 
the tests do not work for it either.

**If I try running the test when the capabilities are set to internetexplorer I get this error:**

```
C:\Projects\build>mocha ietest.js
.
0 passing (42ms)
1 failing

1) Click current location button. Seems to have worked.:
 TypeError: Object function (opt_other) {

    /** @private {!Object} */
    this.caps_ = {};

    if (opt_other) {
        this.merge(opt_other);
    }
} has no method 'internetexplorer'
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\build\ietest.js:9:43)
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1598:20)
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1463:8)
at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
==== async task ====
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:126:14)
at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:196:15)
at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:374:10)
at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:452:12
at next (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:299:14)
at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:309:7
at next (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:247:23)
at Object._onImmediate (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:276:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

**And if I change the capabilities to firefox I get this error:**

```
C:\Projects\build>mocha ietest.js
  .
  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing
1) Click MyNearest current location button. Seems to have worked.:
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:128:16)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:440:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:131:49)
at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:111:30)
at Builder.build (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:106:20)
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\build\ietest.js:10:3)
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1598:20)
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1463:8)
at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
==== async task ====
at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\build\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:126:14)
at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:196:15)
at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:374:10)
at C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:452:12
at next (C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:299:14)
at C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:309:7
at next (C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:247:23)
at Object._onImmediate (C:\Users\akeogh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:276:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

I have been fighting this issue for a long time now without any success, any help really would be appreciated. It may just be something small that I'm not doing correctly but I haven't been able to figure it out.

thanks,
Anthony

Comment: NOt sure about the firefox error, but for Internet Explorer try webdriver.Capabilities.ie(), not internetexplorer()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steve, but when I tried changing the capabilities to ie I got a similar error to the ECONNREFUSED one above.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, see the code example in the WebDriverJs documentation at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Using_the_Stand-alone_Selenium_Server. You will need to install the Stand-alone Selenium Server, and fill in the pathToSeleniumJar in the code example with the appropriate value.

For IE, you do something similiar:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;

var pathToSeleniumJar = 'C:\\selenium-2.41.0\\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar';

var server = new SeleniumServer(pathToSeleniumJar, {
  port: 4444
});

server.start();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer(server.address()).
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).
    build();
```

This should work as the IE Driver should already be in your path. Also see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver for tweaks you may need to do to your IE settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Neil, I've tried your IE example but I get the message "Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://10.0.0.146:4444/wd/hub" which it think is the IP for google but I dont know why it is looking there for the web dirver. In my test I'm using `driver.get('http://www.google.com');` but I have specified the JAR location as you mentioned: `SeleniumServer("C:\Projects\selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar", { port: 4444 });` Would you have any idea why this is.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this question was asked, but for anyone coming across this issue, this might help.

It looks like the Selenium Server hasn't started for you. I wait for the Server to start before executing code against it.

```
function startSeleniumServer(callback) {

   seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(path/to/selenium/server/jar, { port: 4444 });
   var promise = seleniumServer.start();
   promise.then(function() {
      console.log("Selenium Server: Started");
      return callback();
   });
};
```